# how do i make my gridview to fit 100% on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How do i make my gridview's to fit nicely within the screen.
I added this property width="100%" i. However my gridview still extends way beyond my header's width which i have set it as 100%.

[image]

Here are my source code of my gridview for the first attempt.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GWCase" runat="server"  Top="0%" Width="100%" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" Height="199px" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GWCase_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I tried using the css method like this

```
<ul id="assigngw">
<asp:GridView ID="GWCase" runat="server"  Top="0%" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" Height="199px" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GWCase_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
</asp:GridView>
    </ul>
```

Css code :

```
#assigngw {
width:100%;
}
```

Unfortunately both does not work.

Here is my entire source code.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<ul id="assigngw">
    <asp:GridView ID="GWCase" runat="server" width="300px" Top="0%" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" Height="199px" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GWCase_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
</asp:GridView>
    </ul>


<br />
Case ID :
<asp:Label ID="lblCID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;is situation near
<asp:DropDownList ID="lblocation" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lblocation_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="location" DataValueField="location">
    <asp:ListItem>Select Location</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Bukit Batok NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Bukit Panjang NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Choa Chu Kang NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Jurong West NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Nanyang NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Woodlands East NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Woodlands West NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Ang Mo Kio North NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Ang Mo Kio South NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Punggol NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Hougang NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Sembawang NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Serangoon NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Sengkang NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Yishun North NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Yishun South NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Bedok North NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Bedok South NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Changi NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Geylang NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Marine Parade NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Pasir Ris NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Tampines NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Bukit Merah West NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Clementi NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Queenstown NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Jurong East NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Bishan NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Bukit Timah NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Kampung Java NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Orchard NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Toa Payoh NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Bukit Merah East NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Rochor NPC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Marina Bay NPC</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<br />
The following case will be assigned to this selected officer&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLpolice" runat="server" DataTextField="dropdownpolice" DataValueField="dropdownpolice" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="DDLpolice_SelectedIndexChanged1" style="height: 22px"
    AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select Officer</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: @Downvoters - Guys, this question isn't a bad one. It's legit and well formed. Why downvote?

Comment: Actually i was also wondering the same as well. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with your test content and the garbage text.

Add:

```
#assigngw td {
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

This will allow each cell to break on the long sentences that don't fit and will stop it increasing the size of the grid view.

**EDIT**

Try this

```
.gridview {
    width: 100%; 
    word-wrap:break-word;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

The key here is `table-layout: fixed;` as it forces the cells to fit the table instead of the table expanding to fit the cells.

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PntgT/3/)

Comment: There isn't any difference. As for my garbage text, i have set a maximum of 500 words in the textbox with multiline. Hence i randomly typed the maximum of 500 words in order to test and see if the gridview extents all the way which unforunately it did.

Comment: Look at your image, 4th row down. That is **one** word, setting a 500 word limit won't help in this case. Can you create a jsFiddle of the rendered table the browser has please? I should be able to help then.

Comment: i cant seems to run the result though.

However i screenshot the result my browser gave.

http://jsfiddle.net/5uKrh/

http://imgur.com/7cFRuMr
http://imgur.com/7cFRuMr

Comment: Don't paste the ASPX code into jsFiddle, open the page in the browser, view source and copy the rendered html table layout into jsFiddle along with your CSS.

Comment: Here it is. sorry for the trouble. been stuck for days to be that desperate. http://jsfiddle.net/PntgT/

Comment: Actually, wait. Better Idea.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. It works perfectly. Have been trying for days and i finally managed to get it. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also put your gridview in a div, like this
`<div style="width:100%;overflow:scroll;">
<i>your gridview here</i>
</div>`

With this, the gridview doesn't extend beyond page width. But the user will scroll vertically across page to view all gridview contents.

Answer (score 2):

It is the long text without space in the row that is pushing the grid out. You need to add this style attribute `word-wrap:break-word;` to the cell if you want the text to break.

Comment: You mean adding "word-wrap:break-word;" innto the asp:gridview?

Comment: Yes, but is this a real world example. Is it ever going to happen that text of that size is going to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style type="text/css">
        .tblgridview {
            width: 100%;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            table-layout: fixed;
            font-size: smaller;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Please, explain why and how your code works :) that way it may be valuable to less experienced developers