# Gridview is overflowing the page. How to fit it to 100% of page

Tags: gridview, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying all ways to fit my gridview into screen, but it is

1. exceeding the screen
2. Text is aligned in center. I wanted it to be aligned from the start
3. Columns "Main Group" and "Sub Group" are displayed as thin columns
4. Hyperlinks are showing as text

i tried solutions provided on other blogs, but didn't help.

[how do i make my gridview to fit 100% on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338904/how-do-i-make-my-gridview-to-fit-100-on-page)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Labs.aspx.cs" Inherits="LabCentral.Labs" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <%--<style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        table {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

            table th {
                background-color: #F7F7F7;
                color: #333;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            table th, table td {
                padding: 5px;
                border-color: #ccc;
            }

            table tbody table {
                padding: 5px;
                border-color: #fff !important;
            }
    </style>--%>
    <style type="text/css">
        .gridview {
            width: 100%;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            table-layout: fixed;
            font-size: smaller;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <section class="container-fluid">
        <img src="IMAGES/lab_Home-1.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-5" />
    </section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <center>
                                    <h2 class="text-decoration-underline">Simplifying Laboratory Access</h2>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-3 mb-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <center>
                                        <h4 class="h6color">Testing & Calibration Laboratories</h4>
                                    </center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder=" Search"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
                                    <div style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal">
                                            <%--OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanged="GridView1_PageIndexChanged"--%>
                                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Rating_Score" HeaderText="Rating" ItemStyle-CssClass="Rating_Score" HtmlEncode="false">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>

                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="Rating_Score"></ItemStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Lab_Name" HeaderText="Lab Name">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Field" HeaderText="Field">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Discipline" HeaderText="Discipline">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Main_Group" HeaderText="Main Group">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Sub_Group" HeaderText="Sub Group">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Accreditations" HeaderText="Accreditations">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_Person" HeaderText="Contact Person">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email ID">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>

                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProfilePage" HeaderText="Profile Page">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Link_for_certificate" HeaderText="Certificate">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Expiry_Date" HeaderText="Expiry">
                                                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px"></HeaderStyle>
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                            </Columns>
`your text`
                                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
                                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                            <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
                                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
                                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
                                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
                                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />

                                        </asp:GridView>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="HomePage.aspx">< < Back to Home</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```